# Filter an RDD based on number of occurrences

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, apache-spark-mllib

I have an RDD of product ratings using the MLlib Rating object, which is just a tuple of (int userId, int productId, double rating). I want to remove any element from the RDD that is a review of a product with too few ratings.

For example the RDD could be this:

```
Rating(35, 1, 5.0)
Rating(18, 1, 4.0)
Rating(29, 2, 3.0)
Rating(12, 2, 2.0)
Rating(65, 3, 1.0)
```

and if I filtered that to remove any product with less than 2 reviews, it would just filter out the last rating and give back the first four. (I want to filter with a way higher minimum review count than 2, but just for example).

Currently I have this code which outputs a sequence of the product IDs in order of the number of ratings, but I was unsure of a way to filter from the main RDD based on that and it seems inefficient anyway:

```
val mostRated = ratings.map(_._2.product)
                       .countByValue
                       .toSeq
                       .sortBy(- _._2)
                       .map(_._1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can group the *rdd* by *ProductId* and then filter it based on if the length of the group is larger than the threshold (1 here). Use *flatMap* to extract the results from the grouped *rdd*:

```
case class Rating(UserId: Int, ProductId: Int, Rating: Double)

val ratings = sc.parallelize(Seq(Rating(35, 1, 5.0),
    Rating(18, 1, 4.0),
    Rating(29, 2, 3.0),
    Rating(12, 2, 2.0),
    Rating(65, 3, 1.0)))

val prodMinCounts = ratings.groupBy(_.ProductId).
                            filter(_._2.toSeq.length > 1).
                            flatMap(_._2)
prodMinCounts.collect
// res14: Array[Rating] = Array(Rating(35,1,5.0), Rating(18,1,4.0), Rating(29,2,3.0), Rating(12,2,2.0))
```